# One and only one zero comparison with the least operations

Tags: algorithm, if-statement, optimization, logical-operators, bitwise-xor

This might be a silly question, but in some function I have two `int` s, and need to compare them to find `if` exactly one of them is `==0`... Both of the ways I came up with require 5 logical operations, and I can't think of anything shorter... Is there a shorter way?

What I came up with is:

```
int x, y;

if (((x==0) || (y==0)) && (x != y)){} // most obvious option, or:

if (((x^y) == x) ^ ((x^y) == y)){} // looks better, but still 5 ops
```

Comment: I think `x == 0 ? y == 0 ? "BothZero" : "XZero" : y == 0 ?  "YZero" : "BothNonZero" ;` uses only two logic operations in runtime because of how branching works.

Comment: @jrook That's true, but a branching operation is usually more expensive than a logic operation, at least in languages compiled to native code.

Answer (score 3):

The expression `((x^y) == x) ^ ((x^y) == y)` can be simplified in a straightforward way.

`(x^y) == x` if and only if `y == 0`, and likewise `(x^y) == y` if and only if `y == 0`. So the following uses three operations to compute the condition:

```
if((x == 0) ^ (y == 0)) {
    // ...
}
```

This makes sense because using XOR as a logical operator, the result is true if and only if one but not both of the operands is true. So this directly tests whether one but not both of `x == 0` and `y == 0` are true.

Comment: Or `(x == 0) != (y == 0)`, which is a bit easier to figure out by reading it due to symmetry. I guess there should be quite a few ways to do it in 3 operations, and probably none with 2 operations or fewer.

Comment: Oh wow, I have no idea how I missed this! Thanks, that makes perfect sense!

Comment: (my up-vote doesn't show up yet, but this is a full answer)